# How can I preserve new lines coming from a command's output during variable assignment?

Tags: shell, newlines, variable

Consider:

```
$ getfacl somefile.dat     # The output is formatted and contains several new lines..

# file: somefile.dat
# owner: user1
# group: group1
user::rw-
group::r--              #effective:r--
mask:r--
other:r--
$
$ ACL_PERMISSIONS=$(getfacl somefile.dat);
$ echo $ACL_PERMISSIONS;
# file: somefile.dat # owner: user1 # group: group1 user::rw- group::r-- #effective:r-- mask:r-- other:r--
```

So how do I preserve these new lines during variable assignment, so that when I echo `$ACL_PERMISSIONS` I get the same output as `$ getfacl somefile.dat` ..?

Comment: Kindly explain the reason for the -1..?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but my guess would be that it is because this is an issue merely involving missing quotes (which I don't think warrants a downvote, but I've seen it happen before on questions like this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote your expansion, otherwise it will undergo word splitting, which is what you are experiencing.

```bash
acl=$(getfacl somefile.dat)
echo "$acl"
```

Bear in mind that `$(` strips trailing newlines anyway (it is considered a feature). If that is a problem for you, you need to do something like this to preserve them (in bash4+):

```bash
mapfile acl < <(getfacl somefile.dat)
printf %s "${acl[@]}"
```

Comment: Hey @Chris, Thanks! I wasn't aware of 'word splitting' and using quotes around the variable does solve my problem.. Just curious, how can I preserve trailing newlines (not sure where such a thing might help) using ksh..?

Comment: @KentPawar The first method should also work in `ksh`.

Comment: Yup, it does.. Sorry, but didn't quite get your 2nd example.. whats `mapfile` doing..?

Comment: @KentPawar From `help mapfile`: "[r]ead lines from the standard input into an indexed array variable". It essentially reads each line from the output of `getfacl somefile.dat` into an array called `acl`.

Comment: $( strips newlines ? `list=$(ls); echo $list; echo "$list"`  word splitting is demonstrated with `echo $list`, if newlines were stripped then I'd expect the same output with the 2nd echo.

Comment: @ChrisDown - thanks. But seems like mapfile does not come bundled with the Linux/Solaris boxes I am working on..

Comment: @suspectus - Hi! How could I implement the "strips newlines" part in ksh..? I can't find any commands that could do that for me..

Comment: @Kent - hmm strange, In ksh just tried the `list=$(ls)` etc (as above) and `echo $list` strips newlines, `echo "$(list)"` does not.

Comment: @suspectus - your example works fine, its just the `$( strips newlines ? ...` part that throws an error as there is no `strips` command defined on my system..

Comment: @Kent - sorry for confusion. "strips newlines" is not a command it is just text. I think in your case you just need to enclose the variable in quotes as Chris suggested.

Comment: @suspectus `$(` strips *trailing newlines*, not just any newlines.

Comment: @KentPawar Just use the first example, in that case.